# Wordpress posts under content

Tags: php, html, wordpress

How should look my code in order to display a preview of a categories with main main page?
Now its is

```
<?php $posts = get_posts ("category=2&orderby=date&numberposts=3"); ?> 
 <?php if ($posts) : ?>
 <?php foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata ($post); ?>
 <div>
 <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a> 
 </div>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

and below this

```
<?php if(have_posts()): ?>
<?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
    <div class="pageContainer"><?php the_content(); ?></div>   
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php else: ?><div>Sorry, posts are not found.</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This leads to ignore second part...

Sorry for my english.

Comment: what do you mean with 'preview fo categories' ?

Comment: my first part of code - order to display titles by catrgory with id=2. On page, below this part of code i'm try to display content of page use second part, and first part leads to ignore second part, and to display a post

Comment: That code is going to list all the titles first, then once those titles have been listed it will start to print the pages contents. Is that what you want to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <?php 
       // Category posts
       $posts = get_posts("category=2&orderby=date&numberposts=3");
       if ($posts){
          foreach ($posts as $article){
             echo '<div><a href="'.get_permalink($article->ID) ?>" rel="bookmark">'.
                   $article->post_title.'</a></div>';
           }
       }

       // Current page content
       if ( have_posts() ) :
         while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
           <div class="pageContainer">
               <?php the_content(); ?>
           </div>   
        <?php endwhile;
       else:
           echo '<div>Sorry, posts are not found.</div>';
       endif; 
       ?>
```